# How to pass a smarty associative array to an amChart

Tags: php, charts, smarty

I'm new to smarty. I want to display an amChart. I have included this tpl file in another tpl file. I want to pass the smarty associative array to the amChart. How do I do it, because my chart is not being loaded. I wish to pass the smarty array to the chart.dataprovider attribute.

```
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
    chart.valueField = "value";
chart.titleField = "title";
chart.dataProvider = {$chart_data};
chart.write("chart_div");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to recreate it for javascript looping the array with smarty or, much better,  json_ncode the array with php and output the result for javascript to use

Comment: json_ncode worked for me. var foo = {$chart_data|@json_encode};